# Handling Image data from IMFSourceReader and IMFSample

Tags: c++, windows, ms-media-foundation

I am attempting to use the `IMFSourceReader` to read and decode a .mp4 file. I have configured the source reader to decode to `MFVideoFormat_NV12` by setting a partial media type and calling `IMFSourceReader::SetCurrentMediaType` and loaded a video with dimensions of 1266x544.

While processing I receive the `MF_SOURCE_READERF_CURRENTMEDIATYPECHANGED` flag with a new dimension of 1280x544 and a `MF_MT_MINIMUM_DISPLAY_APERTURE` of 1266x544.

I believe the expectation is to then use either the video resizer dsp or video processor mft. However it is my understanding that the video processor mft requires windows 8.1 while I am on windows 7, and the video resizer dsp does not support `MFVideoFormat_NV12`.

What is the correct way to crop out the extra data added by the source reader to display only the data within the minimum display aperture for `MFVideoFormat_NV12`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New media type says this: "video is 1266x544 and you expected/requested, but I have to carry it in 1280x544 textures because this is how GPU wanted it to work".

Generally speaking this does not require further scaling or cropping you already have the frames you need. If you are reading them out of sample objects - which is what I believe you are trying to do - just use increased stride (1280 bytes between consecutive rows).

If you are using this as a texture, presenting it somewhere or using it as a part of rendering, you would just use adjusted coordinates (0, 0) - (1266, 544) ignoring the remainder, as opposed to using full texture.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am still a little confused. I am copying the image data from the `IMFSample` buffer into a texture which will then be rendered. Am I correct in understanding that this texture should be (1266 x 544 * 1.5) bytes in size and have 1280 x 1266 bytes copied in for the Y plane followed by 1280 * (1266/2) bytes for the UV plane?

Comment: `1` there is a good chance you already have a texture, so you don't have to read back and update your own resource. You are interested in finding ways to just copy `2` the concept of strides is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/image-stride), take a look at "padding" - this is what you have in your data and this is what you need to take into account.