# Media Foundation wrong video size

Tags: winapi, video, ms-media-foundation, h.265

Sometimes the source reader returns incorrect video size. It happens with some H265 video files.

This is the reference video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12oH9x7MCW7YFZu1MDKGbOnIt4VvxrgtZ/view?usp=share_link
3840x2160 pixels

```
CComPtr<IMFSourceReader> r;
CComPtr<IMFMediaType> NativeMT;
MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(L"file.mp4" 0, &r);
r->GetCurrentMediaType((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, &NativeMT);
UINT wi = 0,he = 0;
MFGetAttributeSize(NativeMT, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, &wi,&he);
```

This returns 3840x2176. Why?

I will follow up with more problems because this format fails to be converted to another H264/H265 video with Media Foundation.

Comment: I can reproduce with the video using [VideoThumbnail](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/27ffb0811ca761741502feaefdb591aebf592193/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/VideoThumbnail) sample. I have escalated this.

Comment: Microsoft has been having this bug for years. https://alax.info/blog/1935

Comment: @RomanR. it's a bug all right, is there a way to detect that is incorrect? If I know that it is incorrect I can fix it in my video editor.

Answer (score 3):

So you have this media type for the video track:

- `MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE`, 16492674418816 (Type `VT_UI8`, 3840x2176)
- [`MF_MT_MINIMUM_DISPLAY_APERTURE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/mf-mt-minimum-display-aperture-attribute), 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0F 00 00 70 08 00 00 (Type `VT_VECTOR` | `VT_UI1`)

The latter quoted attribute reads as this:

```
{OffsetX={fract=0 value=0 } OffsetY={fract=0 value=0 } Area={cx=3840 cy=2160 } }
  {fract=0 value=0 }
  {fract=0 value=0 }
  {cx=3840 cy=2160 }
```

You should take this into account and be ready to accept samples with 3840x2160 payload being carried in 3840x2176 buffers.

Related Q: [Handling Image data from IMFSourceReader and IMFSample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61880648/handling-image-data-from-imfsourcereader-and-imfsample).

IMO this is still a bug since H.265 demultiplexer is aware that this is encoded video, and padding does not make sense. Decoder would apply this when it sets up textures or buffers with padding, it starts being important only there.

Also, this is a behavior different from H.264 codec AFAIR. And then, again, this side effect AFAIR causes a problem with property sheet handler which displays this wrong resolution for media files.

Comment: But one from Microsoft said, "**this isn't a bug, but is by design**. The analysis shows that the cause of this video being reported at a size other than 3840\*2160 is due to MF_MT_MINIMUM_DISPLAY_APERTURE being used to document the size of the frame that is valid, as explained in the answer by Rob in the forum thread. This is used for multiple codecs for various reasons to encode the portion of the video that is valid, when the frame size recorded is larger. In the case of .h265, the standard requires block sizes of 32*32 and the recorded must be integral divisions of 32."

Comment: [Rob's answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1134688/media-foundation-wrong-size-for-video) about the question.

Comment: Still sounds like bug to be for the reasons explained in the body of the answer. The same reasoning in its entirety applies to H.264 but in that case the implementation is accurate.